# How to fetch music files into app on Android 10 and below in flutter

Tags: flutter, fetch, android-music-player

I created a flutter music app that can fetch music files from the phone storage into the app.It works perfectly on **Android 11** but it is unable to fetch the music files in **Android 10 and below**. I have tried a lot of things but still hasn't worked. here's is the code for fetching the music files

```
    import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:app_settings/app_settings.dart';

class DirectoryLogic{

  List <String> musicFiles = [];

  fetchData(Function function,BuildContext context)async{


    await Permission.storage.request();

    if(await Permission.storage.isGranted){
      print('granted');

      final Directory dir =  Directory((await getExternalStorageDirectory()).path.toString().substring(0,20));

      dir.list(recursive: true).listen((FileSystemEntity entity) {
        if(entity.path.contains('mp3') ){
          musicFiles.add(entity.path);
        }

      },onDone: function,);

    }

    else{
      await AppSettings.openAppSettings();
  }
  }

//  final Directory extDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
//final String dirpath = extDir.path.toString().substring(0,20);
//  print(dirpath);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is probably due to Scoped Storage Access that introduced in Android 10 and 11.

Read https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes

I have fixed this with enabling legacy storage access ([Example](https://github.com/SrilalS/U-Music/blob/V3/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)) but I don't think we can use this much longer as google is restricting it. but for the timbeing this works well.

use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml file as shown in the example.

Comment: when I try to add android: requestLegacyExternalStorage property,
it shows "Attribute requestLegacyExternalStorage is only used in API level 29 and higher"

Comment: ignore it if it compiles and runs fine.